Tensor product of algebraic theories
The following is a theorem from Borceux, Handbook of Categorical Algebra 2:
Theorem 3.11.3 Let $\mathcal{T}$ and $\mathcal{R}$ be algebraic theories. There exists an algebraic theory, written $\mathcal{T}\otimes \mathcal{R}$, such that the following three categories are equivalent:
(1) the category of $\mathcal{T}$-models in $\text{Mod}_\mathcal{R}$;
(2) the category $\text{Mod}_{\mathcal{T}\otimes\mathcal{R}}$ of $\mathcal{T}\otimes\mathcal{R}$-models in $\text{Set}$.
(3) the category of $\mathcal{R}$-models in $\text{Mod}_\mathcal{T}$;
In the above theorem, Borceux is using the term "algebraic theory" for what would otherwise be called a "one-sorted algebraic theory" in the book Algebraic Theories.
Is there an analogue of this theorem for algebraic theories in the more general sense (algebraic theory = small category with finite products)? I also added the tag reference-request because I have not seen other sources which discuss the tensor product of algebraic theories.

Yes, there is an analogue. The 2-category of categories with finite products, finite product-preserving functors, and natural transformations is equipped with the structure of a closed symmetric monoidal bicategory: a classical reference is §6.5 of Kelly's Basic Concepts of Enriched Category Theory (though Kelly only hints at the coherence laws). A more explicit reference is López Franco's Pseudo-commutativity of KZ 2-monads. Neither of these references treat algebraic theories specifically, though.
I'm not sure of a reference for tensor products of (multisorted) algebraic theories explicitly, but there are a few other relevant references in the one-sorted setting:

Algebra valued functors in general and tensor products in particular (Freyd, 1966)
Algebraic Theories (Wraith, 1969)
Commutants for enriched algebraic theories and monads (Lucyshyn-Wright, 2017)

